# How to check if all elements of a 2*2 array are true?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm creating a 4x4 2D array. I need to be notified, or gain a value when all elements have been turned true. Is this as simple as "If the2DArray[] = true { blah blah }" ?

Thanks! 
P.S. I haven't wrote the code yet. I'm asking this question to help formulate the logic of the program.

Answer (score 3):

For 2D arrays, you must manually go through all the elements in the array to check if one value will be false.

An example of this would be:

```
public boolean checkArr(boolean[][] arr) {
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            if(!arr[i][j]) 
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want action to be taken in case all elements are true , you will have to check each element.

```
boolean flag=true;
 for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
   for(j=0;j<4;j++) {
       if(array[i][j] == 'false')
          flag=false;
          return;
    }
  }
if(flag == true)
  // your action
```

Comment: Just to note: when `flag=false;` statement is executed, there's no need to continue checking the rest of the elements in the array of arrays, so it would be better breaking the top `for` loop, or easier, just `return false`.

Comment: Another thing to note: the way you are checking against your array value to 'false' is improper, as single quotes only denote a char and not a String.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could use to be notified when all array elements are true is by wrapping an array element in its own object that fires an on/off event, and wrapping the entire array in an object that fires an allOn event.  Something like this (code is c#, but hopefully you can follow):

```
public class Element
{
    public event Action TurnedOn = delegate { };
    public event Action TurnedOff = delegate { };

    private bool state;

    public void TurnOn()
    {
        state = true;
        TurnedOn();
    }

    public void TurnOff()
    {
        state = false;
        TrunedOff();
    }
}

public class My2DArray
{
    public event Action AllTurnedOn = delegate { };

    private readonly Element[,] array;
    private int numberOfElementsThatHaveBeenTurnedOn;


    public My2DArray(Element[,] array)
    {
        this.array = array;

        foreach (Element element in array)
        {
            element.TurnedOn += OnElementTurnedOn;
            element.TurnedOff += OnElementTurnedOff;
        }
    }

    private void OnElementTurnedOn()
    {
        numberOfElementsThatHaveBeenTurnedOn++;

        int amountOfElements = GetAmountOfElementsInArray();
        bool allElementsAreOn = numberOfElementsThatHaveBeenTurnedOn == amountOfElements;
        if (allElementsareOn)
        {
            AllTurnedOn();
        }
    }

    private void OnElementTurnedOff()
    {
        numberOfElementsThatHaveBeenTurnedOn--;
    }
}
```

The logic for counting if all elements have been turned on assumes that all elements are false to begin with.